# Why this regex fails when there is an extra zero?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have created this regex to match dollar amounts more than $9,000.00.

`\$(?=.{6,11}$)\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*`

But it fails in cases like this,

`$25,000.00. Text Goes here`

`$1,000,000.00`

However it works in cases like this,

`$25,000.0. T`

`$25,000.00`

`$999,000.00`

How to fix this regex?

Comment: *"more than $9,000.00"*: you mean it should match $9,000.01 but not $9,000.00?

Comment: @trincot it should match $10,000.00 or more but not $9,000.00 or $9,999.00

Comment: Is there a maximum amount? The `11` seems to suggest as much, but you don't mention anything about it.

Comment: @trincot Yes, that's the maximum.

Comment: Any requirements about the number of decimals? Apparently you want to accept one decimal and two. More? Would you reject the whole amount when there are 3 decimals? Or would you still accept, but not match the 3rd decimal? Or would you accept all decimals no matter how many?

Comment: @trincot We can only have 2 decimals but decimals can be optional. I don't accept 3 decimals.

Comment: It would be good if you would edit your question and add those extra requirements.

Comment: Well, I just wasted my time on Cash over `$9,000.00`. Come to find out in the comments that's not the number. I wish I could delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues in your regex:

- The look ahead assertion requires the that match can only start in the final 11 characters of the input string, since it has the `$` anchor after at least 6 and at most 11 characters. So it is no surprise that "$25,000.00. Text Goes here" does not match. I suppose you don't want that `$` anchor, and then the 11 is not useful anymore either.
- The look ahead assertion requires that at least 6 characters follow after the currency symbol, however that could include non-digit characters, and so your regex will match the amount in `$300 oh" (6 characters follow after currency symbol).
- There is no provision in your regex for decimals even though you say it works for examples that have decimals. But it will not *include* those decimals in the match. For instance, for input "$300,000.50" it will only match "$300,000" and not the 50 cents. You would need to accept an optional decimal point followed by one or two digits and then require there are no more decimal digits with a negative look-ahead.
- The look-ahead assertion is not the right place to impose a maximum amount, because when you remove the `$` (see first point) you must still require that there are no more digits after the 11th position. Instead, just remove the look-ahead assertion and match the patterns you want in more detail. There are just two options: either you have 2 or 3 digits followed by one digit group (for amounts between 10,000 and 999,999.99) or you have 1 to 3 digits followed by two digit groups (for amounts between 1,000,000 and 999,999,999.99). To avoid that *more* digits follow when no decimal part exists, use a negative look-ahead assertion: `(?![,.]?\d)`.

All this is taken into account in this correction:

```
\$(?:\d{2,3}(?:,\d{3})|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3}){2})((?![,.]?\d)|\.\d\d?(?!\d))
```

On [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/VbaYY6/1)

To allow the same numbers without commas, add `\d{5,9}` as an option:

```
\$(?:\d{2,3}(?:,\d{3})|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3}){2}|\d{5,9})(?:(?![,.]?\d)|\.\d\d?(?!\d))
```

On [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/VbaYY6/2)

Comment: Thank you, it works. I would be grateful if you can add support to the comma less version too so I can match both in one regex.

Comment: Added that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Totally new answer. After closer inspection I see that they have revised
the specifications on this question.

I am submitting this solution based on a $10,000.00 - $999,999,999.00 range
of unacceptable cash amounts. The comma's and decimal are optional.
There cannot be more than 2 consecutive decimal numbers after the period.
Ah, other specifications are dubious.

Note that a text representation of leading zero's is not allowed, which is a
distinction worth investigating as digits `\d` class is covers characters 0-9.

It is hard, if not impossible to match to infinity.
For example, the OP requested to match cash greater than $9,000 (Ah $10,000).
Regex has no representation of quantifiers representing **infinity**  therefore
@Trincot tried to talk him into a max cash amount number to cap it.
In reality, you can only match the infinite with a negative of the finite.
So it is in the cosmos as it is in regex.

The only real way to match a number greater than another number is to
state that it is not in a finite range. In this case not in the range $0 - $9,999.

In this case they have established a range that the cash *cannot* be in.
That apparently is this $10,000.00 - $999,999,999.00 range, which
absolutely does not represent all values greater than $10,000.00

My original answer was to match $0 - $9,000 (original minimum) then post that regex in a negative assertion, thereby matching the infinite set of values
greater than $9,000 which was and is the only answer to matching cash values greater than
a fixed amount.

In the end, parsing values is only a preamble to getting it into a float
and there is no way to glean the final value ahead of that conversion.
Therefore, this is really an exercise in futility.

To that end :

$10,000.00 - $999,999,999.00

```
\$[1-9](?:\d{1,2}(?:,?\d{3}){1,2}|(?:,?\d{3}){2})(?:\.\d{0,2})?(?![,.]?\d)
```

https://regex101.com/r/1h4XW9/1

```
 \$ [1-9] 
 (?:
    \d{1,2} 
    (?: ,? \d{3} ){1,2}
  | (?: ,? \d{3} ){2}
 )
 (?: \. \d{0,2} )?
 (?! [,.]? \d )
```